# Time Complexity Analysis of the Given Code

Tags: time, complexity-theory

How do I find time complexity as a function of the problem size n?

```
sum = 0;
if (EVEN(n)) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            O(logn)
        }
        else {
            sum++;
        }
    }
}
else {
    sum = sum + n;
}
```

Comment: Ummm... the pseudo-code makes no sense. What is the `O(log n)` in the middle? There seems to be a constant-time variant of what you want, but I can't really tell. Please edit the formatting.

Comment: Hi Heman, That is the question i got for my assignment, i couldnt understand why there is an o(logn) in the middle as well. Im guessing its average case running time for the code?

Comment: I believe the `O(log N)` simply means the code within that if statement will run in `O(log N)` time.

Comment: You should format your pseudocode better to be unambiguous

Comment: I will format it better, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

### The answer is: O(N log N)

Considering the worst case scenario `EVEN(n)`, the for loop will execute **N** times or in **O(N)** time.

The worst case complexity of the code inside the for loop is **O(log N)**.

You then multiply the for loop's complexity with the complexity of its contents.

Therefore, **O(N)** * **O(log N)** = **O(N log N)**.

**EDIT**: With regards to the code inside the for loop...

Since the **O(log N)** execution is only run when `i % 2 == 0`, that means it only runs every other iteration of the for loop. Therefore, the true complexity is **O(0.5log N)**, but since you drop all constants when calculating complexity, the complexity is still **O(log N)**, and the final answer is still **O(N log N)**.

Comment: Thanks budi for the explanation, i thought it was o(n) but thanks for the explanation.